# Checkstyle and Generics

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm trying to correct all Checkstyle warnings for my project, but I keep stumbling over something very annoying when I need to construct a class that takes a Generics argument. Take the following line, for example:

```
labels = new HashSet < String >();
```

Then Checkstyle complains that '">" is not followed by whitespace'. So I write the whitespace:

```
labels = new HashSet < String > ();
```

And now it complains that '"(" is preceded by whitespace'.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to bypass it without adding a @SupressWarnings annotation?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me in both the cases.Which ide are you using ?Mine is eclipse.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Helios, you don't get any warnings at all?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Like implied by Oliver, the question was valid for the version of Checkstyle I was using then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are running at least the 5.0 version of Checkstyle as it fixed the handling of generics. See the release notes http://checkstyle.sf.net/releasenotes.html.

Comment: Checkstyle 5.6 still Marks imports who are used to define Generics. We gota wait for fixes.

Answer (score 1):

It probably thinks the `>` is a greater than operator because there is a space before it.

The common way to space generics declarations is like this:

```
labels = new HashSet<String>();
```

Unless your checkstyle rules are tweaked, the above should most likely pass.

Comment: Strangely enough, if I do it this way, it tells me it needs spaces in between the <>. As a matter of fact, I got the project from another location, so I'd have to check if there's a rule override somewhere. I might do that after I sleep a little =D

Comment: Definitely recommend the sleep :) Meanwhile I found this thread where someone else had the same problem. They've also listed the correct checkstyle configuration to make this work: http://forums.topcoder.com/?module=Thread&threadID=512536&mc=6

Answer (score 1):

I have Checkstyle version 6.17 in use and I got this resolved by removing `GENERIC_START` and `GENERIC_END` from the `tokens` field in [WhitespaceAround](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#WhitespaceAround) rule.